# Using BeautifulSoup to scrape the web for an API and deploying on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a very simple API using Flask and am using BeautifulSoup to scrape the data and return json to GET requests. The project works perfectly in my local environment but the web-scraping does't work when I host it on Heroku. I suspect it has something to do with the User-Agent used while web-scraping.

Any advice is much appreciated.

```py
 try:
        page = requests.get(teem, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        score = soup.find(class_="imso_mh__wl imso-ani imso_mh__tas").get_text()
        return translator.translate(score.strip(), dest="en").text
    except:
        return 'ERROR: INVALID ENDPOINT'
```

Comment: How scraping doesn't work is there any error or something. Please include it here. And what happens request json.

Comment: Hi @charchit, as added to the original question, when the code runs on my local machine or I test the API using postman, I get the expected JSON. However, when I run it on Heroku servers, I am always returned 'ERROR: INVALID ENDPOINT'.

Comment: @sahaj If you and your app users can successfully access the app in a browser (or however the app is used), this may not be cause for concern. The errors may be caused by clients (typically web-crawlers) with cached DNS entries trying to access a now-invalid endpoint or IP address for your app.

Refer: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes

Comment: @sahaj i think in Heroku they had mentioned the same error

Comment: @Sahaj This is not the real error, replace `except` part with `except Exception as e: print(e)` this would print the real error also then when running app on heroku go to heroku logs and check for error

Comment: @arunna thanks, I'll take a look at it

Comment: @charchit, I've made the changes and am getting 2021-06-09T19:13:38.888035+00:00 app[web.1]: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
2021-06-09T19:13:38.889280+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.117.146 - - [09/Jun/2021:19:13:38 +0000] "GET /DAL HTTP/1.1" 200 15 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15" as the feedback when I check the Heroku logs, any idea why I would get these on only Heroku and no where else?

Comment: is there anywhere you are using group and try printing page,soup,score before return line and check if anyone of them in None.